# What are the success rates for hunter for hire?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

When you send off hunters it goes through a list of grades for "chance of success" From E to "sparkling" S.

What are the success rates of each letter/sparkled letter? Should I not even bother sending off if it's below a certain grade?

Comment: I am thus far unable to find any sources that spell out an approximate rate for GreatSuccess/Success/Failure based on the letter graded 'odds'. However, I have heard that they *can* on *rare* occasions return with a rare carve, even on a failed mission. So it is almost always worthwhile to at least try sending them off. Just be sure to always pay for the extra help to boost their odds, and select the hunter that's going after something you could use.

Comment: I have found this: [Ping's MH4G Dex](https://sites.google.com/site/pingsdex/pingsmh4gdex/en_us) neat little program that has a hunter for hire section, which would *seem* to indicate the base success rate of every H4H quest... However looking at two of the hunters standing around in my guild hall - one is for a Pink Rathian, the other a Tigrex. The program would seem to indicate that both have a 50% base success rate, but one is sitting at D odds, the other at C. So clearly something about those hunters is influencing their success rate (equipment? hunter rank? both?).

Comment: And I have no idea how much that influence (and the additional influence of about half a letter grade per additional hunter hired) affects the base success rate.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Your Unity level with that hunter will increase their success rate.